# Como salvar informações de uma caixa de texto de html em uma variável em javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Criei uma caixa de texto com tags no html.
Pretendo passar as informações adicionadas nela para uma Array do meu javascript chamada usu.

**Meu Código**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3>Entre com sua aposta para mega sena (Com 6 números)</h3>
  <input type="text">
  <br>
  <input type="button" onclick="correto()"; value="Valide sua aposta">

  <div id="correto">
    <h1>Números Corretos</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="incorreto">
    <h2>Números Incorretos</h2>
  </div>


  <script>
    var usu = new Array(num);
 

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cara, desculpe mas seu código está muito errado e mal explicado. Coloque seu código completo para entendermos melhor.

Comment: Irei fazer a edição do código

Comment: Man, esse html tem alguns erros heim. Mas fala aí quais valores desse código você quer colocar em um array?

Comment: Fiz outra pergunta explicando melhor o meu problema, agradeço a atenção. Estarei passando o link aqui: [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/386637/como-mudar-informa%c3%87%c3%95es-de-um-html-por-meio-de-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer um split no texto para recuperar em forma de array os valores que estão separados por espaço (nesse caso)

```html
<html>

<body>


<h3>Entre com sua aposta para mega sena (Com 6 números)</h3>

<input id="numeros-mega" type="text">

<br> <input type="button" onclick="validarResposta()" value="Valide sua aposta">

<div id="correto">
    <h1>Números Corretos</h1>
</div>

<div id="incorreto">
    <h2>Números Incorretos</h2>
</div>

<script>
    var usu = [];

    function validarResposta() {
        var resposta = document.getElementById('numeros-mega').value.trim();
        usu = resposta.split(/\s+/);

        console.log(usu);
    }
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tente dessa forma. Não sei a sua necessidade real, mas assim dá pra você ter uma base.

Se o valor digitado já estiver dentro do array, então será exibido uma mensagem de alerta e o número não será inserido. O campo também é limpo após você clicar no botão "Valide sua Resposta".

- O indexOf procura se aquele valor que está nele como parâmetro, está presente naquele array especificado (no código desse código, o Array "usu"). Quando não contém o valor, é retornado -1.
- O push adiciona aquele elemento que está nele como parâmetro, na primeira posição vazia do Array. (No caso desse código aqui, adiciona o valor da variável "bot" no Array "usu").

**Veja no console.log que os valores digitados no Array são exibidos lá.**

```html
<html>

<body>

  <h3>Entre com sua aposta para mega sena (Com 6 números)</h3>

  <input type="text" id="campo-texto">

  <br>

  <input type="button" id="botao" value="Valide sua aposta" onclick="gerar()">

  <div id="correto">
    <h1>Números Corretos</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="incorreto">
    <h2>Números Incorretos</h2>
  </div>

  <script>
    var usu = new Array();

    function gerar() {
      var bot = document.getElementById("campo-texto").value;
      if (usu.indexOf(bot) == -1) {
        if (bot != "") {
          usu.push(bot);
          console.log(usu);
          document.getElementById("campo-texto").value = "";
        } else {
          alert("O campo está vazio");
        }
      } else {
        alert("O número já existe no Array");
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```